# Derivative of map from into endomorphisms of $\mathbb{H}$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $\varphi:SU(2)\times SU(2) \rightarrow End(\mathbb{H})$ given by $(A,B)\mapsto (h\mapsto AhB^{-1})$. I have shown that the kernel of this map is $\ker(\varphi)=\{(I,I),(-I,-I)\}$.

I want to calculate the derivative of $\overline{\varphi}:(SU(2)\times SU(2))/\ker(\varphi) \rightarrow End(\mathbb{H})$. But I am not sure how to do this.

Attempt:
I first have tried to calculate the derivative of $\varphi$ in hopes that might help
$$d_e\varphi=d/dt_t=0(h\mapsto exp(tX)hexp(-tX)$$
this gives that $d_e\varphi$ is the adjoint representation?